# Is their any way i can open parallel query tabs

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is their any way for sql developer to show query result vertical one after other

Like below I want to set

If i run 2 select query the ouptut should come vertically one after other

vertically want 2 output

[image]

Any properties available to achieve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your queries as a script, you'll get text output stacked vertically.

Or, open two worksheets.

Short answer: No.